# Different results for IRR from numpy.irr and the Excel IRR function

Tags: python, numpy, excel-formula

I have the following annual cash flows:

```
w=np.array([   -56501, -14918073,  -1745198, -20887403,  -9960686, -31076934,
               0,         0,  11367846,  26736802,  -2341940,  20853917,
        22166416,  19214094,  23056582, -11227178,  18867100,  24947517,
        28733869,  24707603, -17030396,   7753089,  27526723,  31534327,
        26726270, -24607953,  11532035,  29444013,  24350595,  30140678,
       -33262793,   5640172,  32846900,  38165710,  31655489, -74343373,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
               0,  -8727068])
```

I calculate IRR using np.irr

```
np.irr(w)
Out[141]: -0.05393588064654964
```

When I use IRR function in Excel for the same cash flows, I get 12%.
These two functions usually produce the same result. Does anyone know why in this case the results are so different? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the given cash flows, the IRR is not unique; see [Multiple IRRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return#Multiple_IRRs).  Both the numpy and Excel values for `r` satisfy `NPV(r) = 0`, where NPV is the net present value.

Here's a plot of NPV(r) for the data in `w`.  The red stars mark the IRR values (where NPV(r) is zero).

[image: plot]

Here's the script that generates the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


w = np.array([   -56501, -14918073,  -1745198, -20887403,  -9960686, -31076934,
                      0,         0,  11367846,  26736802,  -2341940,  20853917,
               22166416,  19214094,  23056582, -11227178,  18867100,  24947517,
               28733869,  24707603, -17030396,   7753089,  27526723,  31534327,
               26726270, -24607953,  11532035,  29444013,  24350595,  30140678,
              -33262793,   5640172,  32846900,  38165710,  31655489, -74343373,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,
                      0,  -8727068])

r_excel = 0.1200963665

r_numpy = np.irr(w)

rr = np.linspace(-0.055, 0.16, 500)
npvals = np.array([np.npv(r, w) for r in rr])

plt.plot(rr, npvals/1e6, alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(r_numpy, 0, 'r*')
plt.plot(r_excel, 0, 'r*')

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.ylabel('NPV(r) [millions]')

plt.show()
```